# Why do I get error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 -3 10 6 5 0 3 -5 2'

Tags: python, integer

I am attempting to make a string an integer by saying

```
file = open(input("Please enter the name of the file you wish to open:" ))
while True:
    A = file.readline() 
    if(A):
        array.append(int(A[0:len(A)-1]))
    else:
        break
print("The numbers in the file are:", A)
file.close()
```

The file I created has numbers: `1 -3 10 6 5 0 3 -5 20`

Here is the error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 -3 10 6 5 0 3 -5 2'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the error - `'1 -3 10 6 5 0 3 -5 2'` is not a number. It's a `list` of numbers. You need to turn it into a list of strings first.

Also,you shouldn't really use `.close()`. Use `with` instead.

```
fname = input("Please enter the name of the file you wish to open:" )
with open(fname) as f:
    for line in f:
        a = [int(num) for num in line.split()]
        print a
```

Comment: Sorry - the indentation was too far spaced out - so I just moved it a bit, and something happened to that, so that I mislead you on the OP's original post... - my apologies (ie. the OP didn't have the close inside their loop - my mistaken edit put it there)